# How create many formulas with proper syntax

Tags: r, formula, lapply

I would need to fit many models with lapply (some with interaction, others with sum and other just with one indipendent variable) and thus I am applying the following code on this purpose

```
 lapply(c('+', '*'), \(symb) lapply(c('A', 'B', ' '), \(regr) {
      xnam <- 'indipendent'
      fmla <- reformulate(paste(paste0(c(xnam, regr), collapse = symb), '+', '(1|C)'), 
                          response = 'dipendent outcome')}))
```

Unfortunately I am getting redundant and wrong syntax

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + A + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5adcef840>

[[1]][[2]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + B + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5ad9f9838>

[[1]][[3]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + +(1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5a4dbf488>


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent * A + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5af17d7c0>

[[2]][[2]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent * B + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5897f99c8>

[[2]][[3]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent * +(1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5940a2818>
```

I would like just to get rid of "same model syntax" when one is already available. Indeed, the following syntax

```
[[1]][[3]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + +(1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5a4dbf488>
```

is equivalent of

```
[[2]][[3]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent * +(1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5940a2818>
```

and moreover, since I would like to use them as a caption of flextable object I would like to oobtain where the double symbol occurs, just the single one:

```
[[1]][[3]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5a4dbf488>
```

I have tried doing this with `str_replace` from `stringr package` but it does not seem to be applicable to formula object. Thus the final output I would like to achieve is:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + A + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5adcef840>

[[1]][[2]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + B + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5ad9f9838>

[[1]][[3]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5a4dbf488>


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent * A + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5af17d7c0>

[[2]][[2]]
`dipendent outcome` ~ indipendent * B + (1 | C)
<environment: 0x000002a5897f99c8>
```

Is that some possible way to get this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for a regressor number of characters strictly greater than zero and create a regressors vector accordingly.

This implies that the last regressor is the empty string `''`, not the blank space `' '`.

It will also save you a `lapply` loop and a `paste` instruction.

```r
lapply(c('A', 'B', ''), \(regr) {
  xnam <- if(nchar(regr) > 0L) {
    paste('independent', regr, sep = "*")
  } else 'independent'
  reformulate(
    termlabels = c(xnam, '(1|C)'), 
    response = as.name('dependent outcome')
  )
})
#> [[1]]
#> `dependent outcome` ~ independent * A + (1 | C)
#> <environment: 0x000001b523109978>
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> `dependent outcome` ~ independent * B + (1 | C)
#> <environment: 0x000001b523112278>
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> `dependent outcome` ~ independent + (1 | C)
#> <environment: 0x000001b52308a2c8>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-04</sup>